# Difference between pack in dotnet and msbuild

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

I use the new SDK style project of VS2017

In dotnet I can Pack using the command:

```
      dotnet pack project.csproj     --no-dependencies  --no-restore --output c:\packages -p:TargetId=abc -p:configuration=release
```

In msbuild, I can pack using the command:

```
     msbuild project.csproj /t:pack -p:TargetId=abc -p:configuration=release
```

How to set the options of dotnet `--no-dependencies  --no-restore --output`  using msbuild

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `--no-restore` doesn't need to be translated. If you do want to restore, pass `-restore` (short form `-r`) to msbuild.
- `--no-build` translates to `-p:NoBuild=true`
- `--no-dependencies` translates to `-p:RestoreRecursive=false` (note that this doesn't really need to be used together with `--no-restore`)
- `--output` translates to `-p:PackageOutputPath=C:\some\path`

Do note that other commands such as `build` translate `--no-dependencies` to something different: `-p:BuildProjectReferences=false` which does not build project-to-project references, which may be what you want instead.

The full mapping from command line arguments to MSBuild parameters is spread over a few source files in the dotnet/cli GitHub Repo:

- [PackCommandParser.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/95c6eff6daa1a69f29c42b2d405400ad44bdec91/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-pack/PackCommandParser.cs) contains the main `pack` command arguments.
- Some of the [CommonOptions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/95c6eff6daa1a69f29c42b2d405400ad44bdec91/src/dotnet/CommonOptions.cs). are used.
- Since it is a command that supports implicit restore, it uses restore options from [RestoreCommandParser.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/95c6eff6daa1a69f29c42b2d405400ad44bdec91/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-restore/RestoreCommandParser.cs#L45-L98)

More parameters that are supported by the NuGet targets - which you could set from both the command line or the project file - are documented at [NuGet pack and restore as MSBuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets).

Comment: It seems that msbuild restore and build again when packing. How to stop this, or i should use dotnet pack?

Comment: Edited to also show `-p:BuildProjectReferences`.. `--no-dependencies` does something different for different commands (yup, that's super confusing). I also forgot `--no-bulid`.
`msbuild` doesn't restore unless called with `-t:Restore` or `-r`/`-restore`. You'd have to look at a build log to see which targets are called during the build